# Is a job offer with an overnight deadline standard in London?

Tags: software-industry, job-offer, united-kingdom

I've been offered a job the day of an interview but been asked to decide by the following morning.

Is this standard practice for London software engineering jobs?

Comment: No personal experience, but my friends tell that there is a dire need for Software Engineers in London area. However, in that case I would imagine they would do their damnest to try to get you, instead of forcing you to decide overnight, which could scare some people away.

Comment: When you say "offered a job" do you mean you've received a signed contract of employment? Until that happens you haven't been offered the job. If they say to you "We're offering you the job but you have to accept by tomorrow morning" just look puzzled and say you haven't received the contract yet - or just tell them to GTFO because, no, of course that isn't standard behaviour.

Comment: Minor rant, but how is this off-topic as per the tag? It's a bit niche, but there's a software-industry tag and London is the 24th biggest city in the world... so surely that's considered broad enough to go on this site? I feel a meta question coming on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

tl;dr answer - No.

There's two possible reasons I can see - the charitable one is that they want you to make a quick decision so that they can move on to the next candidate promptly if you say no, and have done it in rather a cack-handed and inappropriate manner. The other, and more likely, is that they are trying to bounce you into a quick decision without proper consideration of alternatives. It certainly smells that they've made an offer so quickly - I've certainly received quick offers but when that happened it was clear that they wanted me enough to be accommodating over my time required to decide.

If there were no other red flags at this company and you're considering saying yes, it might be worth asking for a bit more time in order to consult with family/friends - maybe a couple of days. If they refuse or turn hostile, think very carefully before accepting.

Comment: the last para is the most pertinent, in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Echoing Julia, it's not usual to impose a tight deadline like that.

If, however, you like the job - verbally accept it on provision of a satisfactory contract.  Once you have the contract you can take your time reading it, negotiate pay and benefit, and research the company more thoroughly.

If they're desperate to hire you, it should put you in an advantageous position.

Answer (score 4):

Your salary expectation might be far below the average, so they want to close the deal before you get the chance to realize it. The contract could contain parts that are not favorable to you, so they want to avoid you reading it in detail. Lots of other reasons.

If they didn't mention a tight deadline during the interview and that they need you to start immediately, I would tell them you need to read the contract and think about and you will tell them your decission in 2-3 days.